# Apache: SSL certificate not working with www, how to remove?

Tags: apache, ssl, no-www

Im trying to setup our VPS with a newly installed SSL certificate. The certificate is for only domain.com, not www.domain.com. So when a user visits https://www.domain.com they now get an "insecure page" warning - which I of course don't want to have. I want to redirect the user to https://domain.com, but I keep getting stuck in infinite loops all the time..

Here's my virtual host file..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin my@email.com
     ServerName domain.com
     ServerAlias domain.com
     Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/
     DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/
     <Directory /var/www/domain.com/>
        AllowOverride ALL
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog /var/www/logs/domain.com/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/logs/domain.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin my@email.com
     ServerName domain.com
     ServerAlias domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/
     <Directory /var/www/domain.com/>
        AllowOverride ALL
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog /var/www/logs/domain.com/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/logs/domain.com/access.log combined
     SSLEngine on
     SSLProtocol all
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mycert.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mykey.key
     SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/myca.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Im a beginner at this, and I can't seem to find a solution besides buying a wildcard certificate which I really cannot afford..
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might needed to redirect all your www url calls to non-www.. Try the following rewrite rules with your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://example.com/ [last,redirect=301]
```

Replace example.com with your domain name and make sure to put this in the .htaccess at the document root of your website.